# Brannock Device US Size to Nike/Adidas Football Boot US Size

Tags: football, equipment

If I measured as a US size 7 on the Brannock Device, which US size should I pick in an Adidas boot or a Nike boot?

Comment: it was a little unclear what you were asking. I think I've captured your question better through editing, but please re-edit it if I've misinterpreted what you were asking.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [Brannock Device sizing chart here](http://brannock.com/cgi-bin/htmlos.cgi/0020763.1.527647328100000275?), it appears that no further information is given other than the shoe size.

Unfortunately, feet are all very different and the problem with a specific number is that it assumes certain proportions between foot width and length, as well as [arch type](http://www.foot.com/site/arch-types) and other differences.

Furthermore, not only is there variation between manufacturers, different manufacturers' individual products also vary widely.

I am roughly a US size 14. Adidas Copa Mundials in US size 14 fit me perfectly. However, Nike's range of US size 14 indoor football shoes I find are a little short and feel very tight on my heels and toes, even though they fit the width of my foot perfectly.

You will need to try a range of products by a variety of manufacturers to find a boot that fits you well. The best advice I can offer is to stick with the same boot once you have found one that fits you comfortably and works well for your playing style. A lot of time and money (in purchasing shoes that end up not working out) can be wasted if you switch to a new product every time your boots wear out.